# why is this function returning false when it should return true?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a simple code base with less than thirty lines, it has a function called `disable()` where it verifies if a value of an array inside of an array inside of another array (bind to check-boxes) and return true if either:

- **zero** or more than one checkbox checked
- **one** checkbox checked that has a certain value of `null`

here's the function :

```js
disable() {
  if (!this.checked_y.length) {
    return true;
  }
  this.checked_y.forEach(year => {
    year.specs.forEach(sp => {
      if (sp.spec == null) {
        return true;

      }
    });
  });
  return false;
}
```

You can find the full code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cqo4Lv7g/)

Comment: Hint: Think about what function `return true` is returning from. What function is `return true` in?

Comment: Try adding a created() to call the disable() method when the vue is created, `created() { this.disable(); },`

Comment: Carcigenicate that seems a little bit advanced for me but ill check it out

Comment: AntonyMN  no use  i tried created() and mounted() but ):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not return for an outer function from an inner callback, but you could use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) for the nested arrays and return if true with a short circuit.

```
function disable() {
    return !this.checked_y.length
        || this.checked_y.some(year => year.specs.some(sp => sp.spec == null));
}
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the best practices around `==` vs `===`, especially when comparing against `null`....

Comment: thank you nina, it worked . (can not return for an outer function from an inner callback) is this global concept or just for javascript because its the first time i heard of it and it seems very important. yeah im so newb :)

Comment: i think it's in all languages the case. `return` ends only the own function.